# I am creating a server job but facing this error in datastage , Plz help if you have any idea about this error

Tags: datastage

CamelServer..Sequential_File_2.DSLink3: ds_seqopen() - Win32 error in CreateFile - Access is denied.

Comment: Provide more information - this is not adequate! Read the intro how to ask questions and provide details needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a user rights issue, as if the user running the job does not have the necessary rights on the directory where you are reading/writing from a file. A little more context would help better understand the issue (i.e is the job run manually from the Director or is it scheduled, is the offending directory local on the server, etc..?).

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that error occurs for the sequential file stage.  It is unclear if this issue occurred on the first run of job or subsequent runs.

DataStage jobs can run under different userids unless you have all the users credential mapped to common id such as dsadm.

The most likely cause of above error are: 
 1. The target directory where you have selected to create sequential file has directory permissions that do not permit file create/write by the userid that is running the job.
 2. OR, the job was previously run with different userid, creating a file owned by that userid, and new job run is with new userid that does not have permission to overwrite the original file.

Check the job log to see what userid is running the job...the userid is on every event message.  Then confirm the file name and location sequential file is trying to write, and at OS level, confirm if that file already exists with different userid (if so, try updating file permission) and also confirm that directory permissions allow write by the userid now running the job.